# VSCODE Solidity Extension to avoid syntax errors

Tags: visual-studio-code, blockchain, solidity

So, I have been using my vscode for solidity for a while now, but, I keep getting syntaxes errors.

I have tried different extensions, but it still not working.
It's still shows syntax error with redmark all over the code even though it compile successfully.

[image: See Image Here]

Comment: You can go to where it says "Problems (69)" and see what things it's complaining about

Comment: NO, It is not an error per say. It's the solidity syntax highlight error. I think I need an solidity extension to fix it.

Comment: Recommendations for tools or libraries are off-topic on Stack Overflow. Please see the [help] for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I see you have a `hardhat` project: the solution for this is to disable the Solidity extension by Juan Blanco and install the [Solidity and Hardhat support by the Hardhat team extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NomicFoundation.hardhat-solidity).

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is still an issue but you might have conflicting solidity extensions(mine was conflicting with that of Juan Blanco). try uninstalling any unnecessary extension, the recommended extension is that from Nomic foundations

Cheers

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Delete every vscode extension about Solidity, like `Solidity Language Support`
`solidity-solhint`... and then choose one to install.

Answer (score -1):

Try installing [solidity extension by `Juan Blanco`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JuanBlanco.solidity)